# Azure CLI - Enable auto shutdown

Tags: azure

I am unable to find az commands that allow me to enable the Scheduled auto-shutdown of a VM.  I can do this easily through resource manager when deploying a new vm or editing an existing one, but how can I do through bash commands on the Azure Cloud Shell?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, currently, Azure CLI 2.0 does not support enable the Scheduled auto-shutdown of a VM.

In Azure Cloud Shell, you could use [`crontab`](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm) to shutdown a VM at specific time. Please refer to the following steps:

1.`export VISUAL=vi` in Cloud Shell, then you could edit crontab task with `vi`.

2.Write a script `~/.autoshutdown/autoshutdown.sh`

```
az vm deallocate -g <name> -n <>
```

3.Give executable permissions.

```
chmod +x ~/.autoshutdown/autoshutdown.sh
```

4.Edit crontab task, `crontab -e`, if you want to shutdown your VM at 22:00, add the following line to the file.

```
0 22 * * * ~/.autoshutdown/autoshutdown.sh
```

5.Check crontab task, `crontab -l`

You could check the similar [blog](https://michaelblouin.ca/blog/2016/04/23/auto-shutdown-azure-linux-vm-inactivity/).

Comment: I see you ask a question on SF, the root reason is your script file type is dos(when you create a file on Windows, the file type is dos by default), but on linux it needs unix file type. So, you will get the error log. You could use `dos2unix` change file type. Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82726/convert-dos-line-endings-to-linux-line-endings-in-vim

Comment: But Cloud shell does not install dos2unix, you need transfer on your local linux or use Notepad ++ change it.

Comment: `DOS vs. Unix Line Endings` please refer to this link:http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html